# how to extract lists having same element value?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of list like this `data=[["date1","a",14,15],["date1","b",14,15],["date1","c",14,15],["date2","a",14,15],["date2","b",14,15],["date2","c",14,15],["date3","a",14,15],["date3","b",14,15],["date3","c",14,15]]`  I want to get lists having the same 2nd index. i tried this code but i got 9 lists when i just need 3 lists.

```
    data=[["date1","a",14,15],["date1","b",14,15],["date1","c",14,15],["date2","a",14,15],["date2","b",14,15],["date2","c",14,15],["date3","a",14,15],["date3","b",14,15],["date3","c",14,15]]
    for i in  data:
        a=[]
        for j in data:
            if (i[1]==j[1]):
                a.append(j)
        print(a)
```

i expected to get `["date1","a",14,15],["date2","a",14,15],["date3","a",14,15]`
                  `["date1","b",14,15],["date2","b",14,15],["date3","b",14,15]`
                  `["date1","c",14,15],["date2","c",14,15],["date3","c",14,15]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data=[["date1","a",14,15],["date1","b",14,15],["date1","c",14,15],["date2","a",14,15],["date2","b",14,15],["date2","c",14,15],["date3","a",14,15],["date3","b",14,15],["date3","c",14,15]]

from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

print(
  [list(v) for k,v in groupby(sorted(data, key=itemgetter(1)), key=itemgetter(1))]
)
```

In order for groupby to work the data has to be sorted.

Depending on your use case, the list instantiation of the iterator might not be needed. Added it to see proper output instead of `<itertools._grouper... >`